# How to serialize string geojson in Django when part of multipart?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, geodjango

I am sending a `multipart` POST. One field of the data sent is footprint which is string geojson. I converted it to string since it cannot be send as a `dict` object unlike when sent POST as `json`.

```
self.thumbnail = open('apps/data/thumb.png','rb')

self.footprint = """{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[121.79168701171875, 16.909683615558635], [122.12539672851561, 16.909683615558635], [122.12539672851561, 17.19983423466054], [121.79168701171875, 17.19983423466054], [121.79168701171875, 16.909683615558635]]]}"""

self.data = {
        'thumbnail': self.thumbnail,
        'footprint': self.footprint,
        }
self.client.post('/data_management/capture_group_products/',
                                    data=self.data,
                                    format='multipart')
```

I am using a Field Serializer in Django to extract the geojson and input to a [GeometryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geometryfield).

```
class FootprintSerializer(serializers.Field):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        geom_data = data
        #geom_data = json.dumps(geom_data)
        print(geom_data, type(geom_data))
        return GEOSGeometry(geom_data)

#footprint = FootprintSerializer(source='*')
```

When I input it to [GEOSGeometry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#creating-a-geometry), when the data is in string, I get the error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

```
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[121.79168701171875, 16.909683615558635], [122.12539672851561, 16.909683615558635], [122.12539672851561, 17.19983423466054], [121.79168701171875, 17.19983423466054], [121.79168701171875, 16.909683615558635]]]} <class 'str'>
```

But when I use `json.dumps(geom_data)`, I also get backslashes from the geojson and get the error: `ValueError: String input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB.`

Backslashed geojson:

```
"{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[121.79168701171875, 16.909683615558635], [122.12539672851561, 16.909683615558635], [122.12539672851561, 17.19983423466054], [121.79168701171875, 17.19983423466054], [121.79168701171875, 16.909683615558635]]]}" <class 'str'>
```

I also have tried: `geom_data = json.dumps(json.loads(geom_data))`, and also did not work. Had error like the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The returned object must point to the field.

```
class FootprintSerializer(serializers.Field):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return {"footprint": GEOSGeometry(data)}
```